# check user status in laravel vue

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have middleware where i check user status if is online or offline and it's working if i use blade, but since i'm using `vue.js components` i don't know how i can pass that to component.

in blade i can use:

```
@if($user->isOnline)
Online
@else
Offline
@endif
```

this is my `user` model:

```
public function isOnline()
{
  return Cache::has('user-is-online-' . $this->id);
}
```

now my question is **How can I use `isOnline` in my components?**

*PS: if you need any code i share just let me know*

Comment: have you called `isOnline` with your user model

Comment: This function is in my user model yes

Comment: then you have to load in in a cnstructr

Answer (score 1):

If you used blade to get the variable, you can only get it on page load. If your vue is not written in the blade file then your vue can't get the variable in your blade.

I would suggest you to make an API call using [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) or something to your Laravel during the created life cycle of your vue component to get the variable.

```
// Vue
axios.get('example.com/api/users').then((res) => {
   this.users = res.data;
}

// Laravel
Route::get('/users', UserController@index);

// Controller
public function index() {
    return User::all()->map(function ($user) {
        $user->isOnline = $user->isOnline();
        return $user;
    });
}
```

Comment: And how would be the controller part look like?

Comment: And one more thing, since this is get request how would i pass user ids into it? Example, in my users page i have list of all my users where i show their names and photos, how can i send each of them id to this get request?

Comment: The idea is the same, you call an endpoint in your created lifecycle and it return you a list of the users's name, photo, isOnline status.
I have changed my example above.